# Emacs 24.3.1 and ECB 2.40 Error: ECB can only be used with cedet [1.0pre6, 1.1.9]

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb

Running Ubuntu 12.10 with Emacs 24.3.1 and ECB 2.40. Not sure what actually caused this, other than an apt-get update && upgrade I ran a couple days ago.

It started when I rebooted my computer and I ran Emacs and did M-X ecb-activate I would get the following error:

> ECB 2.40 - Error: ECB can only be used with cedet [1.0pre6, 1.1.9]! Please install it and restart Emacs!

I tried a couple of things but have not figured out what exactly caused this issue. I did an apt-get update && upgrade several days ago IIRC and it did update a bunch of packages, so thats a possibility. I ran M-X cedet-version and got:

```
 CEDET Version: 2.0
            Requested   File        Loaded
 Package        Version     Version     Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:        2.0     nil     ok
  eieio:        1.4     nil     ok
  semantic:     2.2     nil     ok
  srecode:      1.2     nil     Not Loaded
  ede:          1.2     nil     Not Loaded
  speedbar:     1.0.4       nil     1.0
  cogre:        1.2     nil     Not Loaded
  cedet-contrib:    1.2     nil     Not Loaded
```

Any thoughts on what is going on here?

Comment: What worked for me (after some more googling) was to edit ecb/ecb-cedet-wrapper.el - find the following line in that file:

    (defconst ecb-cedet-required-version-max '(1 1 4 9)

And replace the first '1' to a '2':

    (defconst ecb-cedet-required-version-max '(2 1 4 9)

Restarted emacs and everything is working fine.

Comment: please, look to my answer about fresh versions of ECB/CEDET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [fork of ECB](https://github.com/alexott/ecb) that works with fresh Emacs & CEDET versions. You can install it either manually, or via [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/) (see instructions on the end of page on how activate MELPA).

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me (after some more googling) was to edit ecb/ecb-cedet-wrapper.el - find the following line in that file:

```
(defconst ecb-cedet-required-version-max '(1 1 4 9)
```

And replace the first '1' to a '2':

```
(defconst ecb-cedet-required-version-max '(2 1 4 9)
```

Restarted emacs and everything is working fine.

Comment: Or under ecb-2.40/ecb-upgrade.el for the same const.

Comment: Thanks for the info, not using ECB anymore too many moving parts for what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

After a LOT of googling, the only trick that did it for me was found [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729865) : add

(setq ecb-version-check nil)

to my emacs init file.